# Why is RadioCheckBox bad redrawn in sublayouts in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

Its only visual problem but not good for refreshing pages or navigate to component using Radiocheckbox, if RCB is in main Vertical or Horizontal Layout works fine, RCB is shown normal, if RCB I use in sublayout in main layouts, like formlayout, gridlayout or other vert or hori layouts, RCB is redrawn(animated) strange from right side to left to position in layout, it takes about second after refresh, it is possible to fix it to show immediately like textfields etc.?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot and the code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: sure thanks [link](https://media.giphy.com/media/2WHcGI2395FgtlaLcD/giphy.gif)

Comment: Ok, the glitch is clear to see, now how about the code to reproduce it?